My TextView is not showing up within my RecyclerView
Ok, so I changed up my code that was showing the TextView. I wanted to make it so it was all spaced out correctly... Anyways. Once I did that the time frame TextView stopped showing up. I've tried using everything I can think of and I'm stumped... Hopefully, you guys can help!
Here's my XML for the list items for my RecyclerView...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
    android:id="@+id/Cardviewparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50sp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/TODOSCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="250sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TODOSCheckBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deleteImage"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTimeframe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Timeframe"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/deleteImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Here is my recyclerview ViewHolder code...
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private CheckBox TODOCheckBox;
    private TextView txtTimeframe;
    private ImageView deleteImg;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TODOCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.TODOSCheckBox);
        txtTimeframe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimeframe);
        deleteImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage);

    }
}

I've tried to reset the constraints, ask the googles, and I've even asked ChatGPT but I've had no luck...

Your code looks good. Are you setting proper text to text view? Set some hard code text in texview and try it.

yeah, I've just checked your code and it looks fine exception there is no hardcoded text for the preview as said by @DeepuGeorgeJacob

It is the time frame text view that isn't showing text actually.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/edit_text_color"
        app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clip_board" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Clipboard"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
                android:textColor="@color/text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_list"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/menu_list"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_12sdp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/icon"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/dotsthreevertical" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDateTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="3/18/24 3:38:02 PM"
                android:textColor="#7F8288"
                android:fontFamily="@font/poppins"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_list"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

you can use this recyclerview item code to show ui properly

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Here is the code that I used that worked. Thank you all for your help!
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_background"
    android:id="@+id/Cardviewparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/TODOSCheckBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/TODOSCheckBox"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/txtTODOTimeframe" /> 

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTODOTimeframe"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Timeframe"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/deleteImage"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deleteImage"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

